# Where to ask about Stack Overflow for teams

Tags: discussion, meta, off-topic, scope, stack-overflow-for-teams

**When should questions about [Stack Overflow for teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) be asked here on Meta Stack Exchange and when on Meta Stack Overflow?**

The tag wiki excerpt is not really useful, as it doesn't specify when a question should be asked here.

> Most questions about Stack Overflow for Teams (a private Stack Overflow environment for a group of developers) should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow, not here.

<s>I will suggest an update for the tag wiki when there is a consensus for my question.</s> Shadow Wizard has changed the excerpt to include better guidance.

Comment: MSO is supposed to be about SO issues, but SO for teams is not SO, it's just another site (or set of sites) which happens to have "SO" in its name. Meta questions about them are markedly off-topic on MSO, while they're on-topic on MSE because these sites are still part of the SE network in some way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion, a question about Stack Overflow for Teams should be **asked on Meta Stack Overflow unless it affects multiple network sites**.

So these questions should be considered on-topic:

- [Unable to delete a non-Stack Overflow profile while in a team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324417/unable-to-delete-a-non-stack-overflow-profile-while-in-a-team)
- [/users/integrations/slack/<user id> leads to 404 on other SE sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379980/users-integrations-slack-user-id-leads-to-404-on-other-se-sites)

And such questions would be considered off-topic:

- How to create a team?
- Who can edit my posts in a team?
- Teams not shown in the incognito mode

However, a Stack Exchange developer [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379980/users-integrations-slack-user-id-leads-to-404-on-other-se-sites#comment668870_379980) that the Teams developers probably monitor Meta Stack Overflow more than Meta Stack Exchange, so when in doubt, ask [over there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).