# Should Stack Overflow for Teams be on topic on meta SE?

Tags: discussion, meta, scope, stack-overflow-for-teams

While it has been [asked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324424/where-to-ask-about-stack-overflow-for-teams) - there's been a significant change in Stack Overflow for Teams. It's still 'formally' hosted on the Stack Overflow website, but you can access your teams from nearly anywhere on the network.

In a conversation with [Teresa Dietrich on SE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8793976#8793976) she mentioned:

> Well, displaying Teams across the network is my first step to trying to make it feel like an ecosystem

MSE is for questions about the *network* as a whole. While I don't advocate for a mass move of questions across from MSO (it would be a monumental mess) or making questions on teams off-topic there (It's their decision) - but at this point, should we consider SO for Teams a network-wide product, and should it be on-topic for MSE?

Naturally, we'd need staff support to pick up and direct these questions appropriately but it seems inline with what seems to be the company's viewpoint.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Teams integration with the rest of the network has been removed, so this question isn't relevant anymore.

Comment: That its no longer on topic - as per Cat's answer is relevant

Comment: I edited the note in as someone just used it as now-false justification that Teams questions are on-topic on MSO.

Comment: The "only applicable to one specific site" close reason shouldn't be used when the "one specific site" is this very site, Meta SE.

Comment: To the close voters, I'm curious: What "one specific site" does this belong on?

Comment: @Spevacus Stack Overflow, which is still the only site where Teams is relevant. It's not relevant to any other site.

Comment: On the other hand, its irrelevant there now. I'm internally debating asking a question about supporting teams on 'some' public platform site cause the current model dosen't work for me. I'd dare say the post is obsolete but sorting this out is low priority for me while I'm in the midst of needing my spoons for things that matter more

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard But... It's asking if we should permit its use on this site. How could a question like that in any way be better fitting on another site?

Comment: I voted to close as "no longer reproducible" since the main context of this question was the left navigation bar, which at the time was tied to Teams but is no longer as of the dissociation between Teams and the public sites. I'm not sure why other close voters picked "specific site".

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of [With Stack Overflow Teams moved, where do Meta questions about it belong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385124/with-stack-overflow-teams-moved-where-do-meta-questions-about-it-belong) because it contains more updated information.

Answer (score 13):

**Update:** Teams questions [are no longer accepted on the meta sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423395/2157772). The left bar on the public sites is now a completely separate feature from Teams.

---

This is my personal musing on the subject along with a bit of internal discussion about it but it's not an "official" preference - interested to know if this seems like a good paradigm for this.

---

Teams is still predominantly a Stack Overflow product - Teams are hosted on SO and the only way they reach out to the network is in the left navigation. For the most part, it still feels to me that Teams questions should remain on SO for the time being. That said, there may be issues that affect non-SO sites due to the sidebar's appearance. This includes bug reports like [Translation for "Learn more" not used in SO for Teams](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362267/translation-for-learn-more-not-used-in-so-for-teams) .

After discussing this internally a bit with some people, I think what would be helpful to us is the following:

1. In general, <s>questions about Teams should continue to live on Meta Stack Overflow</s>.
2. If questions about the left navigation come up, they can be asked here or on MSO since the left-nav is network-wide and well-supported here on MSE.

This means we don't need to do any migrating of historical posts. It also maintains the paradigm we're currently under, so there's less confusion for the MSE community.

Comment: I think we do need an official response ASAP though. Teams questions will [keep coming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363525/348196) unless there's official guidance. Also, if the decision ends up being that only left navbar questions are on-topic, maybe you should consider removing the [stack-overflow-for-teams] tag from Meta.SE.

Comment: Issues like this generally are up to the community. The voting here seems pretty clear.

Comment: @Catija So, is the [status-review] tag needed now?

Comment: @Catija Now that Teams is no longer hosted on SO, how should we deal with Teams questions appearing here on MSE going forward? It feels like they should be allowed now that Teams has its own domain, but at the same time, Teams is mainly (only?) advertised on SO.

Answer (score 5):

> While I don't advocate for a mass move of questions across from MSO (it would be a monumental mess) or making questions on teams off-topic there (It's their decision)

I'm not sure it would be worse than the alternative—they're [pretty easy to find](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-for-teams), and splitting it across sites would create an unfortunate two-sources-of-truth problem, where we're trying to create a knowledge base twice rather than once (this occasionally happens with MSE and other metas already).

If Teams is on-topic at both sites, then questions will potentially end up being answered twice rather than linked as duplicates, with one place likely having a better answer. The result that users will need to know to search *both* sites, and many will likely fail to find the information they're looking for.

I generally agree with your arguments about making it on-topic here and involving MSO in the decision, but there should really be *one* canonical spot for it on the network, wherever that may be.

Comment: I tend to agree but it's going to be difficult to make users not intuitively think of MSO when trying to ask about something that has "Stack Overflow" in its name.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yeah, though it could be partly (mostly?) addressed through migration, just as such questions are today when asked on MSE.  Perhaps a migration path could be added?  Either way, I still think it should be in one spot, but there's definitely room for debate about what, exactly, that spot should be.