# Why was my "not reproducible" flag declined on a fixed issue?

Tags: discussion, flags, meta, declined-flags

Today a new answer was posted on [Can't start a numbered list on a number other than 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137077/571958). The issue seems to have been [fixed since 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239121/571958) by default on all sites.

This makes the issue described in the question not reproducible anymore. In the question itself, there is a line trying to demonstrate the problem which currently doesn't make much sense:

> 2. this should be a 2. not a 1. as I wrote 2. but it changes automatically to 1.

If that is not the definition of "not reproducible" I don't know what is...

Why was my flag on this question declined?

Comment: While less official, the [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252990/282094) explains this at greater length: > "By that logic, whenever a bug is fixed we should also remove the bug tag because there is no longer a bug, it has been fixed.". ... "However, once a question is "completed" and has received an adequate final outcome, we shouldn't change it to another "completed" status based on the previous completed reason. - We'll just be chasing our tails. - That is, "status-completed" is job done, finished, nothing to see here, leave it now.".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Close flags are declined when the outcome of the [Close Votes review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/80215) is Leave Open, while nobody has cast a confirming number of close votes (one if hammered, a quorum otherwise) with the same reason as you in the mean time (inside or out of the queue).

Why did I leave that question open?

1. Bugs/feature requests which have been addressed by a deliberate change in the system should be tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [**not** closed as not reproducible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218344/560258).
2. Other users voted to close it as a duplicate of an older question, which is generally fine, except that the newer question had an authoritative answer by a (then) staff member. So I chose to close it the other way around. If I *had* closed it as a duplicate, your flag would be marked helpful.

To clarify, while it *is* visible in the Close Vote review queue that there are pending close *flags* (versus just pending close *votes*), it's not always visible who cast the flag(s) or which reasons they chose (and it's never obvious).

Here is an example from Stack Overflow:

[image]

(the Needs more focus is a flag, not a close vote)

Comment: On multiple occasions I've had flags declined which have been on posts that've gotten closed. There's something not right here.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. if the review is completed (and results in a Leave Open) and the question is closed outside the queue, the flag stays declined.

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that policy regarding fixed bugs (although I don't completely understand/agree with it...). Thanks for the link. I *did* see your comment on the question-in-question and guessed it has something to do with it, but wasn't sure what

Comment: @Tomerikoo you're welcome. I didn't decline it deliberately, but I think the system was right in declining it in this case.

Comment: @Glorfindel Sure, I completely understand. I don't mind the declined flag (it is basically the first one...) just wasn't sure why the question shouldn't be closed with that reason to which you answered as well... I still find it weird though. That quote I put here really makes the question confusing...

Comment: I see the "No longer reproducible" close reason used incorrectly quite often (though the confusion is acceptable, imo, because it's not clear when you should NOT use it) - How do you think we can improve that? Should we update the usage guidance field for the close reason?

Comment: @Spevacus I'm not 100% sure but I thought updating the usage guidance would technically make it a new close reason. Which is something we should do if it leads to major problems, but I think the community here is quite good at keeping these open in the review queue (unless, like in this case, a duplicate is found).

Comment: @Tomerikoo great. It's indeed very confusing since one of the edits made the bug disappear. I'll have a look at what I can do to make it clearer.

Comment: It *can* be updated, but it requires a CM to approve (Catija [elaborates on that here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362584/622284)) - Which is not super ideal. Mods could retire the old close reason and propose and approve (requires one mod to propose and one to approve) a new one in its place.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, regarding [Glorfindel's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372373/why-was-my-not-reproducible-flag-declined-on-a-fixed-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1243568_372375), I edited the [other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2627/6) and *reintroduced* the bug; so now it's clearer what the bug being reported is (and hopefully future fixes can't break the edit). Fortunately the example enclosed in code markup ( "{}" ) wasn't updated, so it was only a matter of reintroducing the original information.

Comment: @Rob I did happen to see your edit (before your comment) and it indeed makes the problem more clear. Thank you. So both questions at least make more sense and I learned the policy about closing bugs (which I'm slowly starting to agree with :))

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a side effect of how closing as a duplicate works.

1. You flagged this question, that puts it in the close queue.
2. The people looking at whether this question should be closed found another question asking the same thing. Then we need to decide whether to close this question as not-reproducible or as a duplicate
3. The duplicate brigade (including me) were winning.
4. A moderator then stepped in an decided that the duplication should be the other way round i.e. this question should be the main and the other question the duplicate.
5. Closing the other question as a duplicate of this automatically clears the flags/closure of this question because we want to avoid question a) being a duplicate of question b) which is then a duplicate of question a)...

Comment: Point 5 is interesting. Does closing as duplicate always clear the flags/CVotes on the target? I can understand for the duplicate votes, but the rest?

Comment: As far as I'm aware it clears all close votes.