# With Stack Overflow Teams moved, where do Meta questions about it belong?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope, stack-overflow-for-teams

Last year, [Journeyman Geek asked this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362494/244695) about where Stack Overflow Teams questions belong. I tend to agree with most of [Catija's reasoning at the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362536/244695)

> Teams is still predominantly a Stack Overflow product - Teams are hosted on SO and the only way they reach out to the network is in the left navigation. For the most part, it still feels to me that Teams questions should remain on SO for the time being.

The problem is that part about "predominantly a Stack Overflow product" is [no longer true](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421530/2370483) (per staff)

> To get to the meat of your question "Why is the removal of Teams from stackoverflow.com necessitating the removal of all ties?", we’re currently decoupling Stack Overflow for Teams from stackoverflow.com as part of a larger project to achieve SOC 2 Type 2 and ISO 27001 certification in the future. I can’t go into further detail at this time (a more detailed Meta post is coming later next year). This also helps Stack Overflow better service, test, and improve Teams without making infrastructure changes to our public site (and vice-versa),

To put it another way, SOT is now fully divorced from Stack Overflow. It no longer appears in any navigation (save for the "Looking for your Teams? " link in the network-wide side bar). That modal now says

> Stack Overflow for Teams has its own domain!
>
> You can now access your Teams at stackoverflowteams.com. Teams no longer appear in the left sidebar on stackoverflow.com. Check your email to learn more about these changes.

The only "Stack Overflow" part that remains is now the name. Should we continue to migrate questions [like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422282/2370483) to Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: I would like to know too. For the exact same reason as last time 

Comment: Have you tried https://meta.stackoverflowteams.com ? :P

Comment: @Glorfindel actually it's totally expected that paying customers will indeed have their own place to report bugs and ask for support. Sending them to ask in foreign and hostile places is not a good idea, and likely the major reason why people stop using Teams.

Comment: Just FYI: The question which you've linked as an example for migration isn't a great example for migration, because it's a user account issue to which the answer is "use 'Contact Us'", as it is in basically all cases that involve such issues.

Comment: For support questions from existing Stack Overflow for Teams: Enterprise and Business customers, users should open a support ticket at https://s.tk/support to get priority support from Stack Overflow staff. Such support questions from existing Stack Overflow for Teams: Enterprise and Business customers are considered off-topic on all Meta sites and should be closed. [Note: that's per directive from SE Staff, including the shortened URL. SO is particularly concerned about Enterprise customers, but the response applies to Business too](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=62537773#62537773).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Support questions from existing Stack Overflow for Teams customers should be closed, and the users should be directed to https://s.tk/support.

For support questions from existing Stack Overflow for Teams customers, users should open a support ticket at https://s.tk/support to get priority support from Stack Overflow staff. Such support questions from existing Stack Overflow for Teams customers are considered off-topic on all Meta sites and should be closed. Note: that's [per directive from Stack Overflow staff](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=62537773#62537773) (moderator-only link), including not expanding the shortened URL. Stack Overflow is particularly concerned about Stack Overflow for Teams: Enterprise customers, but the response applies to Stack Overflow for Teams too.

### Meta discussions *internal to a Team* belong on the Team

Meta discussions about issues that are *internal to a Stack Overflow for Teams team* are off-topic on all public sites.

### *Current* status

The following is my understanding of the *current* status for various types of questions. It reflects what's historically been on-topic on Meta Stack Overflow with some adjustments. It also reflects information that is contained in the [Stack Overflow for Teams product pages](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/pricing/) and what is displayed to users for the Free, Basic, and Business plan levels of Stack Overflow for Teams. It does *not* reflect potential changes in direction from Stack Overflow as a result of moving to the https://stackoverflowteams.com domain, because, as far as I know, no additional information has been provided by the company.

#### Stack Overflow for Teams

Support is provided via the [web portal](https://s.tk/support) and email. On-call weekend & holiday support is available for Business and Enterprise plans.

Additional support resources include resource center access, which I assume is [this](https://stackoverflow.help/en/).

The Enterprise plan also includes a dedicated Customer Success Manager.

Both the Enterprise and Business level product have [additional support packages available](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/customer-success/).

##### On-topic for [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

- Basic, *general* questions about Stack Overflow for Teams, excluding pre-sales questions for the Enterprise plan.

  - For pre-sales questions for the Enterprise plan, users are directed to fill out a contact form in a popup, which can be opened by clicking "Talk to an expert" on [the pricing page](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/pricing/#p-pricing-grid-enterprise). I *assume* that such questions should be considered off-topic for public sites.

Comment: Well, that's only your personal opinion, and even as SO mod, you're only one and there are many others, each with their own opinion. And I'm seeing Teams questions being closed as off topic on MSO, meaning one just need to be lucky. Until a time mod wars will start over this, and SE staff will bother to post official policy.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars While there is a portion of this answer which is my opinion, I've tried to be clear where that's the case. The substantial majority of this answer is based on explicit statements by the company of what support is offered for the various Stack Overflow for Teams plans and an explicit response from the company to a direct question I asked them about how to handle support questions for Stack Overflow for Teams: Enterprise and Business on MSO and MSE (to which they responded that such questions should be closed and users directed to the support portal).

Comment: Mod wars sound a *whole* lot more fun than Teams support questions, so I'm not sure what you're complaining about, @ShadowWizard. Also, do you have a source for your claim that SO mods are not a hive mind, sharing the same opinions?

Comment: @Cody I see you're in festive mode, that's good. :-)

Comment: Per my [most recent MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422537/after-the-split-between-stack-overflow-for-teams-and-the-main-stack-overflow-sit), the prior provision that allowed Teams members to post on MSO without 5 reputation seems to have stopped working since the split. Some people favor this new status quo since one no longer has to pony up money to make a Team making it easier to post spam there. Might want to take a look at that post.

Answer (score -5):

Each team has (is) its own meta (like on MSE or [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/meta) sites), but each is also free to set up an additional site if they wish to separate the discussions, or use MSO.

Examples (Team access only):

- [Charcoal meta](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/charcoal/questions/tagged/29)
- [SOBotics meta](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/sobotics/questions/tagged/3)
- [Staging Ground Testing meta](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/staging-ground-testing/posts/tagged/3)

"Charcoal" and "SOBotics" implemented it with a meta tag, and "Staging Ground Testing" uses multiple tags like MSE.

While the [staff support](https://stackenterprise.freshdesk.com/support/tickets/new) link uses FreshDesk (different from our other sites), the contact link directs users to [Stack Overflow meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-for-teams), with the appropriate tag.

Comment: While all of this is true, we do need an official policy here. People do want to discuss the overall product itself and we need guidance where that discussion should happen.

Comment: I mean, what it currently does is definitely something to include here, but given it's doing what it currently does *because* it was directly linked to SO, means maybe that's not the best place going forward, given it's been unlinked?

Comment: @KevinB, as a moderator Machavity is in a better position to set Stack Overflow policy, each site is free to set their own guidelines; within limits. --- The [tag:discussion] tag invites questions and answers that are: "Questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and are often subjective.", if he didn't want such answers it would be tagged differently.

Comment: No, Teams are not welcome to use Meta Stack Overflow for Meta discussions that are about issues *internal to their Team*. Such discussions should be on their team. *General* support questions about Stack Overflow for Teams are on-topic for Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Put another way, what i meant was you've effectively just stated how so for teams support is currently handled... The question/discussion here is whether it should remain that way now that it's been separated. I don't see how this answer makes an argument in either direction

Comment: Note: my saying "General support questions about Stack Overflow for Teams are on-topic for Meta Stack Overflow" is the *current* status. It does not reflect any changes which might have recently happened.

Comment: Kevin, you can interpret my affirmation about how things are done as such, or not so. I think the direction is clear, it's just much shorter than @Makyen's article.