# Stack Overflow Labs page has inaccuracies

Tags: discussion, design, meta, stack-overflow-labs

There are several errors on the Stack Overflow Labs webpage.

The [page for the question formatting assistant](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/question-formatting-assistant/) has the MSE logo, not the MSO logo, and Meta is generally not spelled as META by anyone here.

[image]

Amusingly the SO labs logo has a more correct MSO logo as part of it.

[The chat decipher tool](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/chat-decipher/) page *does* link to MSE, but it’s also called META - and, while I embarrassingly missed it, it doesn't quite [fit us based on the guidance we were given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385124/with-stack-overflow-teams-moved-where-do-meta-questions-about-it-belong).

[image]

It would be nice to have a style guide in place (which does not refer to the meta sites as META) to avoid confusion, ensure logos are accurate for users familiar with the network, as well as updates to guidance to fit what actually is the case as well as hopefully a better understanding of the network and resources of the network from people working on projects here.

Comment: Well, [the MSE logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMklm.png) is all caps

Comment: @RandomPerson-onstrike everyone knows that MSE logo is written in lowercase Cyrillic characters: мета.

Comment: Maybe the are afraid of being mixed up with a company formerly known as Facebook?

Comment: "It would be nice to have a style guide in place" – for reference, we do have [a website for the Stacks design principles](https://stackoverflow.design/) that includes a "Brand" section, but it doesn't currently mention anything about Meta sites. I've now suggested adding something there about this.

Comment: What part of complaining about things seems out of spirit with the strike, @ElementsinSpace?

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike Pointing out inaccuracies with this new Labs page is is similar to editing/refining/curating/moderating it.  And, it's helping SO inc. with its push for AI related experiments.

Comment: The spirit of the strike to me is for the company to do better and actively and actually understand the needs and culture of the community. I feel like it's in line with that